# Ant exec - cannot run program 'start' CreateProcess error=2

Tags: windows, ant, exec

I can't run the windows 'start' using ant exec. Ant version 1.7.1.

Here is sample build.xml to recreate the problem

```
<project name="test"  basedir="." default="test-target">
<target name="test-target">
        <exec executable="start">
            <arg line="cmd /c notepad" />  
        </exec>      
</target>
</project>
```

getting the following error when I execute this build file:

```
Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "start": Cre
ateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

My env is Windows XP, Ant 1.7.1
I am trying to run this from DOS prompt.
I rule out any PATH related issues, as I could run 'start cmd /c notepad' from DOS promt manually.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

cheers
a s

Comment: Additional Comments:

I needed this as part of bigger project, where in I need to start multiple app servers (managed servers inside app server) in a scripted way. The build.xml for this project has been given by the vendor, and its fairly complex. I can edit the code a lil bit, but not much in any fundamental way, because its quite long and complex and difficult to analyze the impact.

Comment: The intent of using 'start' instead of 'cmd' is that, when each app server is starting, it starts in a separate window/DOS-prompt, and we continue working on main DOS-prompt. If I use 'cmd', I will not be able to achive it.

Similarly if I use exec attributes like vmlauncher="true" it works, but when I am running multiple servers, after successful starting of 1st server, ant will not get the control back from OS and waiting forever. Alternatively, using spawn="true" is also not suitable to my problem requirement.

Answer (score 15):

start is not an executable but is an internal command of the cmd.exe shell, so to start something you'd have to:

```
<exec executable="cmd.exe">
        <arg line="/c start notepad" />  
    </exec>
```

EDIT:

For spawning multiple windows, this should work:

```
<target name="spawnwindows">
    <exec executable="cmd.exe" spawn="yes">
        <arg line="/c start cmd.exe /k echo test1" />  
    </exec>
    <exec executable="cmd.exe" spawn="yes">
        <arg line="/c start cmd.exe /k echo test2" />  
    </exec>
</target>
```

but you mentioned that spawn="true" is not applicable for your environment, why is that?

Comment: Hi, thank you. Pl read my additional comments, and pl suggest if I can achieve the same (additonal dos-prompt/window for each of my app server start) using cmd instead of start

Comment: thank you. 
The vendor's build.xml has input, output, etc. in the exec statement, and hence I can't use spawn.

Answer (score 1):

my solution

```
<project name="test"  basedir="." default="test-target">
<target name="start-init">
        <exec executable="where" outputproperty="START">
            <arg line="start" />
        </exec>
</target>
<target name="test-target">
        <exec executable="${START}">
            <arg line="cmd /c notepad" />  
        </exec>      
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `<exec executable="start.exe">` ? Or start.bat ?

Also, where is `basedir="."` pointing to? If you place a `<echo message="basedir = ${basedir}"/>` just before your `<exec>` tag, does it print the correct folder (the one with the "start" program in it)?

Additionally, you could add `<echoproperties />` before `<exec>` to see all visible properties.