# ANT Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cp ": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ant, exec

I'm trying to use ANT to copy files from one directory to another directory on Linux.

Firstly I used copy task, it works fine but the file mode is not preserved.
Then I changed to use , and that's where I got stuck.

My target is like:

```
<target name="test">
    <echo message="${basedir}"/>
    <exec executable="cp " os="Linux" spawn="yes">
        <arg line="-p"/>
        <arg line="/tmp/jmap.dat"/>
        <arg line="/tmp/jmap.dat1"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

The output I got is:
test:
     [echo] /Users/bpel/mywork/projects/bpel-psr/utils

> /utils/build.xml:38: Execute failed:
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run
>   program "cp ": java.io.IOException:
>   error=2, No such file or directory

I also tried something like:

```
<exec executable="cp -p /tmp/jmap.dat /tmp/jmap.dat1"/>
```

and it doesn't work either, it seems cannot find `cp` command, but if I manually run `cp -p /tmp/jmap.dat /tmp/jmap.dat1`, it just works fine.

I've been googling around and found no help.

The [similiar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920882/ant-exec-cannot-run-program-start-createprocess-error2) doesn't solve my problem:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a space after the `cp` command:

```
<exec executable="cp " os="Linux" spawn="yes">
```

That's telling it run a command called `"cp "` (with the space). This is confirmed by the error message:

> Cannot run program **`"cp "`**

In fact, the answer is in the subject of the question :)

Take the space out, it should be fine:

```
<exec executable="cp" os="Linux" spawn="yes">
```