# Executing an external executable in a working directory containing spaces in Java?

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have a specific need to unrar files found in different subdirectories during execution of my program on Os x. I do this by calling the freeware command line tool unrar, which works very well.
However, unrar will always unrar files in the current working directory, which means that I have to specify a working directory for the executed process or get every unpacked file in my .jar home folder. 
This is easy enough to do using either the processBuilder.directory(dir) or `runTime.getRuntime().exec(args,null,dir)` for example where dir is a File.
This works excellent but not when the working directory contains a space. As a short example:

```
File dir=new File("/Users/chargedPeptide/rar 2");
String[] cmd = { "/Users/chargedPeptide/rar/unrar", "e", "-o+","/Users/chargedPeptide/rar", "2/weather.rar"};
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd,null,dir);
int exitValue=pr.waitFor();
```

Will not work, while using: `Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);` instead will launch the command successfully but leave me with all of the files in the jars working directory.
Using processbuilder instead and using p`rocessbuilder.directory(dir);` to set the directory
exits with the message:

```
Exception: Cannot run program "/Users/chargedPeptide/rar/unrar" (in directory "/Users/chargedPeptide/rar 2"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Help? How do I handle the spaces? I've tried adding backslashes before the spaces to make them literal no help since the File object treats them like actual part of the path.

Edit: To make the whole thing a bit more clear:
1. I have a separate method that feeds the execute method a command and a directory to processbuilder, all directories are found by the previous method and exist. This works except when the dir contains a space.
2.I need to set the working dir or the command will execute in the wrong place.
3.Parsing the file object by:
    dir=new File(dir.tostring.replace(" ","\ ");
to put a backslash in front of all spaces does not work since the java File object then looks for a path containing actual backslashes. No luck.
4.Using rt.exec instead of processbuilder dosen't help either.

Any ideas most welcome.

Comment: if unrar has some extension (like .sh), can you try with putting them in the cmd array?

Comment: also see http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4 if it helps

Comment: Thank you for the link, while not helping me with this particular problem, rhe redirecting output to a file example helped me with a separate one. unrar seems to have no extension.

Comment: you said 'external executable' in the subject, so it needs to be having some extension? If it is internal commmand may be you have to invoke another command first like we do in windows. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920882/ant-exec-cannot-run-program-start-createprocess-error2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
dir.mkdirs();
```

before launching the process.

This creates the missing directory.

**Edit**:

This looks strange.

```
String[] cmd = { "/Users/chargedPeptide/rar/unrar", "e", "-o+","/Users/chargedPeptide/rar", "2/weather.rar"};
```

If this was a shell you'd write:

```
unrar e -o+ "/Users/chargedPeptide/rar 2/weather.rar"
```

You actually have to put the .rar file in quotes, since otherwise it will be interpreted as 2 arguments to the process.

The way you've split 'cmd' will do exactly that, break the rar argument in two. Try:

```
String[] cmd = { "/Users/chargedPeptide/rar/unrar", "e", "-o+","/Users/chargedPeptide/rar 2/weather.rar"};
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should be clear, the directory exists, in my actual code it is fed in by another method. It seems to be the space in this case "rar 2" that is not handled well by the method and the directory is shown as not existing.

Comment: New to asking questions about code so thanks for your patience.

Comment: Are you sure it is the directory that it's not finding. `Exception: ... No such file or directory` could indicate the `unrar` executable is not found. Does it a) exist and b) is chmod a+x?

Comment: Yes, it executes well with other files in directories that do not contain spaces, and the crash occurs in processBuilder when calling the .directory() method.

Comment: Scratch that, the crash occurs on execution.

Comment: seems to be a problem with cmd, please see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920882/ant-exec-cannot-run-program-start-createprocess-error2

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work, but can you try putting a / at the end of the path.
i.e.,

```
File dir=new File("/Users/chargedPeptide/rar 2/");
```