# Firing command using java runtime class on a windows machine

Tags: java, windows, runtime.exec

I am trying to fire the following command on a windows(that came as part of a product we have bought):

`start /wait setup /z"/sfC:\temp\input_file.txt" /s /f2"C:\temp\newlogfile.log"`

Now the sad part is that I am failing to run the command using a java program that I wrote. (I have to run it as a part of something else, hence the need of running it through java)

Here is my code:

```
String[] cmd = new String [6];

cmd[0] = "start";
cmd[1] = "/wait";
cmd[2] = "setup";
cmd[3] = "/z\"/sfC:\\temp\\input_file.txt\"";
cmd[4] = "/s";
cmd[5] = "/f2\"C:\\temp\\newlogfile.log\"";


try
{
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
}                               
catch(IOException e)    
{   
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here. 
This is the output I am getting:

`java.io.IOException: CreateProcess: start /wait setup /z"/sfC:\temp\input_file.txt" /s /f2"C:\temp\newlogfile.log" error=2
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:108)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:466)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:607)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:480)
    at SilentAgent.fireCommand(SilentAgent.java:316)
    at mainClass.main(mainClass.java:15)`

Comment: what means "failing"? Did your PC catch fire? Or do you get an exception?

Comment: @ThomasUhrig extremely sorry I did not paste the exception. Somehow I forgot even though I knew I must paste it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
String[] cmd = { 
    "cmd.exe", 
    "/c", 
    "start", 
    "/wait", 
    "setup",
    "/z\"/sfC:\\temp\\input_file.txt\"", 
    "/s",
    "/f2\"C:\\temp\\newlogfile.log\"" 
};

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Reason: `start` is an internal command available only from inside a `cmd` shell.

Comment: Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920882/ant-exec-cannot-run-program-start-createprocess-error-2

Answer (score 0):

Do this way:-

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
    "start ",
    "/wait ",
    "setup ",
    "/z\"/sfC:/temp/input_file.txt\" ",
    "/s ",
    "/f2\"C:/temp/newlogfile.log\""});
```

Comment: this really didnt help. actually it messes up the command by adding quotes everywhere. I tried : `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
    "start /wait setup /z\"/sfC:\\temp\\SILENT_AGENT.txt\" /s /f2\"C:\\temp\\silent_setup.log\""});` but that didnt help either; same exception ..

Comment: @RitwikG just try once with what I have posted. It worked for me and tried to open the Windows XP Setup program.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that you java program is located in the same directory of the 'start' program?

If not, pass the command string as a whole string

```
try { 
    String command = "start /wait setup /z\"/sfC:\\temp\\input_file.txt\" /s /f2\"C:\\temp\\newlogfile.log\"";
    // The third parameter is the current working directory 
    Process p = runtime.exec(c, null, new File());
} catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `start` is not a custom program. It is a standard Windows command available in every path.