# Start A Program On A Certain Screen

Tags: java

I'm making a program which for myself personally, would be very useful and remove one of the many things that annoy me. :p To sum it up, I'm making a java application to register a global keyboard+mousemotion listener, and when a certain key on the keyboard is pushed it opens a program. What my java program would do, is before it goes directly to the program to open it, the java program will intercept the call and say 'open on the screen that contains the cursor'. And then will continue to launch the program, but make it open on screen 1,2,3,4 etc.

What my question is, how can I make for example google chrome open on screen 1,2,3,4 etc. Is it possible with java?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the java Runtime class. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800226/firing-command-using-java-runtime-class-on-a-windows-machine) Maybe you can tell your operating system which screen you want via terminal. (In linux DISPLAY env variable.)

Comment: I'm not sure what command to use though(I'm using windows). But, I'm hoping someone on here would know.